# Cygwin startup script

Tags: bash, cygwin, startup, startupscript

How can I run a script inside cygwin after it launches?

I want to automatically add some mounts and run other scripts inside cygwin whenever it starts. I see that in linux it is as simply as adding a shell file inside etc/init.d
However, i tried adding this dir and chmod +x add a shell, chmod that shell file, but does not work.

Also if there is a way to run scripts when closing like umount, rmdir and others.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
~/.bash_profile
```

AKA

```
C:\cygwin\home\CPJ\.bash_profile
```

With a stock install this file is read on Cygwin startup. If you would like to add more files you can edit the `.bash_profile` file, for example

```
source foo.sh
source bar.sh
source baz.sh
```

[Bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry to add to this very old question, but I think the accepted answer above has a glitch.

Try to add a command to your .bash_profile as follows which I use for example to open a local SSH port:

```
ssh -D1080 root@localhost -g localhost
```

When you login interactively, another SSH session starts, which starts another, and another, and you're in an endless loop.

Thought this might help someone..

**.bash_login** is what you actually need :P

Comment: Please elaborate on what the glitch is,

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by combining a few of the given answers.

```
In Cygwin
```

So first of all I ran `which bash` and changed to that directory.

Then I opened up the `.bash_profile` and tacked on the code I wanted to run at startup. (For me it was simply auto changing dir)

Then just save the changes, restart Cygwin and Boom! I was in my new dir :)

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Are there certain things that cannot and should not be done in the .bash_profile file?